# Method causing script to fail

Tags: javascript

I am having a lot of trouble with my method. The code works fine without it but, fails altogether with it. I want it to determine if either field is blank.

If there is a better way to do it other then the If Else, I am certainly open to that.

```
function showPerson ( ) {   //method that fails
    if ( this.firstName != " " && this.lastName != " ") {
        document.writeln(this.lastName + "; " + this.firstName);
    } else if (this.firstName !=  " "  && this.lastName = " ") {
        document.writeln( this.firstName);
    } else  if (this.firstName = " " && this.lastName != " ") {
        document.writeln(this.lastName);
    }  else {
        document.writeln("Unknown");
    }
}

var Person = function (firstName, lastName, areaCode, phone) {   /objector constructor
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.areaCode = areaCode;
    this.phone = phone;
    this.phoneNumber = "(" + areaCode + ")" + phone;
    this.show = showPerson; 
}

function getInfo() {    //prompts user for info
    var firstName = prompt("What is your first name: ");
    var lastName = prompt("What is your last name: ");
    var areaCode = prompt("What is your area code: ");
    var phone = prompt("What is your phone number: ");
    return new Person(firstName, lastName, areaCode, phone);
}



var user = getInfo();   //create object

user.show();            //show object
```

Comment: What does "fails" mean? Does it explode?

Comment: Don't use `document.writeln`.

Comment: @SLaks sorry about that. It simply doesn't execute. As far as I can tell.

Comment: What do you see in the console?

Comment: `=` is not what you want.

Comment: I am unsure how to see that. I was just opening in it in the browser. It is suppose to prompt me for the data (via prompt() ) but, with the method added nothing happens.

I can't see what is really wrong with the method but, then again I am brand new. Very frustrating

Comment: Press F12 to open the dev tools, then use its debugger.

Comment: Seems to not like my if else
    ReferenceError: invalid assignment left-hand side

} else if (this.firstName !=  " "  && this.lastName = " ") {

Comment: I'm not answering this question with this comment but I just want to point out that `this.firstname != " "` isn't as good as `this.firstname.trim() != ""` It handles more cases when the string is empty...

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see neither `Person.show()` nor `showPerson()` is ever called. So why should it be executed?

**EDIT :**

You have assignments `=` instead of compare operators `==` or `===` in your `if else` block.

**EDIT 2 :**

Check if you really want to use `" "`, i think you want `""`

I have changed your code and made a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2p34me8n/

Comment: @AndrewBoen watch out for the `=` in your `if else`

Comment: Thanks! I had forgotten about the == vs =. So now the code is  working but, the logic is failing (defaults to the first IF)

Comment: @AndrewBoen You shouldn't compare with `" "` but with `""` for empty string.

Comment: thank you again. Now the logic seems to be flowing correctly. I do apologize for my stack overflow etiquette, new here as well.

Comment: @AndrewBoen happy i could help. Don't worry too much about etiquette. Sometimes people downvote questions, if they consider them "unclear" or "to easy", etc.. but don't let yourself be discouraged from asking.

Answer (score 0):

Change it to:

```
function showPerson ( ) {   //method that fails
    if ( this.firstName != " " && this.lastName != " ") {
        document.writeln(this.lastName + "; " + this.firstName);
    } else if (this.firstName !=  " "  && this.lastName == " ") {
        document.writeln( this.firstName);
    } else  if (this.firstName == " " && this.lastName != " ") {
        document.writeln(this.lastName);
    }  else {
        document.writeln("Unknown");
    }
}
```

**Also:**

I just want to point out that this.firstname != " " isn't as good as this.firstname.trim() != "" It handles more cases when the string is empty...